# JavaScript simulate first item onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id='+ i +' onclick='dropDown()'>example text</li>
    <li>Hidden content</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id='+ i +' onclick='dropDown()'>example text</li>
    <li>Hidden content</li>
</ul>
```

I'm interested if there is a way with pure JS code that if you clicked `<li>` in second `<ul>` simulate somehow to pass completely the first `<ul>` and make second `<ul>` be first. NO need to move or so.

```js
function toggleClass(element, className) {
  if (!element || !className) {
    return;
  }

  var classString = element.className,
    nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
  if (nameIndex == -1) {
    classString += ' ' + className;
  } else {
    classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex + className.length);
  }
  element.className = classString;
}

function dropDown(el) {
  toggleClass(el.nextElementSibling, 'overlayOpen');

}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlayOpen {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick='dropDown(this)'>example</li>
  <li class='overlay'>Hidden stuff</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li onclick='dropDown(this)'>example</li>
  <li class='overlay'>Hidden stuff</li>
</ul>
```

**Please don't suggest any Jquery solutions.**

Comment: It's possible to do this - but there's modifications that would make it easier.  For a start, both your `li` elements have the same `id`, which will cause non-deterministic behavior.  They also have the literal value `+ i +`,  which may also cause issues since the space character can have semantic meaning.

Comment: Can you please edit on snippet? Thanks

Comment: I hesitate to try, I don't understand what you mean by this "somehow to pass completely the first <ul> and make second <ul> be first. NO need to move or so".  It's pretty unclear

Comment: I also not undestand the question. You need to hide everything else or what?

Comment: I want to ignore first `ul` and simulate like the second `ul` is first one

Comment: You want what exactly to ignore the first `ul`?  If you attach a click handler to the second `ul` it's not going to do anything to the first `ul` anyway.  Simulate what?  Nothing interacts with any element unless you add it and you have added nothing that interacts with either `ul`, so there's nothing to simulate except for your class toggles.  Is that what you meant?